# React Components Not Loading Correctly on Initial Load and Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, package.json

Description:

I am building a React application that uses Material-UI, react-router-dom, and Redux. My problem is that the components are not loading correctly on the initial load and every time I refresh the page. This issue occurs regardless of the component being refreshed. It also only happens when I deploy it live. It works without issue locally

Here's a brief overview of my application:

1. The App.js file uses the BrowserRouter and Routes components from react-router-dom to handle navigation between different pages.
2. I have a custom Sidebar component that contains NavLinks to different routes in the application.
3. I use Material-UI components for styling and layout.
4. Redux is set up with a basic store and reducer configuration, but the components do not seem to rely on it at the moment.

I have tried the following solutions to resolve this issue, but none have worked so far:

1. Ensuring that the BrowserRouter wraps the entire application.
2. Moving the BrowserRouter and Routes components into the main index.js file.
3. Implementing the useEffect and useState hooks in the Sidebar component.

   ```
   Package.json:                                                                             {
     "name": "my-website",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "homepage": "https://anderson-cory.com",
     "dependencies": {
       "-": "^0.0.1",
       "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
       "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
       "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
       "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
       "@mui/material": "^5.12.2",
       "@mui/styles": "^5.12.0",
       "@mui/system": "^5.12.1",
       "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
       "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
       "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
       "axios": "^1.3.6",
       "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
       "cors": "^2.8.5",
       "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
       "express": "^4.18.2",
       "heapdump": "^0.3.15",
       "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
       "package": "^1.0.1",
       "pg": "^8.10.0",
       "react": "^17.0.2",
       "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
       "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
       "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
       "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
       "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
       "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
       "react-scrollbars-custom": "^4.1.1",
       "react-tsparticles": "^2.9.3",
       "redux": "^4.2.1",
       "tsparticles": "^2.9.3",
       "typescript": "^4.4.4",
       "web-vitals": "^3.3.1"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "node --max-old-space-size=512 server.js",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject",
       "server": "node server.js"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": [
         "react-app",
         "react-app/jest"
       ]
     },
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
       ]
     },
     "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
     "main": "index.js",
     "keywords": [],
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "devDependencies": {
       "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
       "uglify-js": "^3.17.4"
     }
   }
   ```

   ```
   App.js:                                                                              import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
   import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
   import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
   import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
   import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
   import { styled } from '@mui/system';
   import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
   import Home from './components/Home/Home';
   import About from './components/About/About';
   import Projects from './components/Projects/Projects';
   import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
   import Education from './components/Education/Education';
   import Experience from './components/Experience/Experience';
   import Skills from './components/Skills/Skills';




   const theme = createTheme({
     palette: {
       background: {
         default: '#228B22',
       },
     },
     typography: {
       fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
       h1: {
         fontSize: '3rem',
         fontWeight: 500,
       },
       h2: {
         fontSize: '2.5rem',
         fontWeight: 500,
       },
       h3: {
         fontSize: '2rem',
         fontWeight: 500,
       },
       h4: {
         fontSize: '1.5rem',
         fontWeight: 500,
       },
       h5: {
         fontSize: '1.2rem',
         fontWeight: 500,
       },
       h6: {
         fontSize: '1rem',
         fontWeight: 500,
       },
       body1: {
         fontSize: '1rem',
       },
       body2: {
         fontSize: '0.875rem',
       },
     },
   });

   const AnimatedBackground = styled('div')`
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: -1;
     background: linear-gradient(135deg, #228B22, #FFDB58, #87CEFA, #E6E6FA, #DDA0DD);
     background-size: 400% 400%;
     animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;

     @keyframes gradient {
       0% {
         background-position: 0% 50%;
       }
       50% {
         background-position: 100% 50%;
       }
       100% {
         background-position: 0% 50%;
       }
     }
   `;

   const StyledSidebar = styled(Sidebar)(({ theme }) => ({
     position: 'fixed',
     left: 0,
     top: '50%',
     transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
   }));

   const App = () => {
     const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {
       const timer = setTimeout(() => {
         setIsMounted(true);
       }, 100);

       return () => clearTimeout(timer);
     }, []);

     if (!isMounted) return null;
     return (
       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         <Router>
           <CssBaseline />
           <AnimatedBackground />
           <Box display="flex" minHeight="100vh">
             <StyledSidebar />
             <Container maxWidth="md" minWidth="60%">
               <Routes>
                 <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                 <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                 <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />} />
                 <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
                 <Route path="/experience" element={<Experience />} />
                 <Route path="/education" element={<Education />} />
                 <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
               </Routes>
             </Container>
           </Box>
         </Router>
       </ThemeProvider>
     );
   };

   export default App;
   ```

   ```
    Sidebar.js:
   import React from 'react';
   import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
   import { Avatar, Box, Typography, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
   import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
   import {
     Home as HomeIcon,
     Info as InfoIcon,
     Work as WorkIcon,
     Code as CodeIcon,
     School as SchoolIcon,
     Email as EmailIcon,
     Build as BuildIcon,
     LinkedIn,
     GitHub,
   } from '@mui/icons-material';
   import useTypingEffect from './useTypingEffect';


   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
     avatarContainer: {
       display: 'flex',
       flexDirection: 'column', // Change flexDirection to 'column'
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.8)',
       borderRadius: '1rem',
       padding: '1rem',
       zIndex: 1000,
       //marginLeft: '200px',
       height: '100%',
       width: '100%', // Add a width to the sidebarContainer
       marginTop: '11%',
       marginBottom: '5%',
       boxShadow: '0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
       border: '3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)',
       borderLeft: '10px solid green',
       transition: 'all 0.3s ease-in-out',
       '&:hover': {
         boxShadow: '0 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
         transform: 'scale(1.02)',
       },
     },

     avatar: {
       width: '75%',
       height: '75%',
       objectFit: 'cover',
       borderRadius: '50%',
       border: '3px solid #000',
     },

     listItem: {
       display: 'flex',
       justifyContent: 'flex-start',
       flexDirection: 'row',
       marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
       borderRadius: '5px',
       padding: '5px',
       flexWrap: 'wrap',
       maxWidth: '100%', // Add a maxWidth to prevent overflow
       overflowX: 'hidden', // Disable scrolling by hiding overflow
       overflowY: 'hidden',
     },

     listItemButton: {
       padding: theme.spacing(1),
       margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(34, 139, 34, 0.8)',
       borderRadius: '50%',
       '&:hover': {
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(34, 139, 34, 1)',
         transform: 'scale(1.1)',
         transition: 'transform 0.3s ease-in-out',
       },
       flexGrow: 1, // Make the buttons scalable within the container
       flexBasis: 'auto', // Allow the buttons to adjust their width
       whiteSpace: 'nowrap', // Prevent the button text from wrapping to the next line
       width: '20%', // Set the width to be a percentage of the avatar container's width
       maxWidth: '100%', // Limit the width of the button to its parent's width
     },
     '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
       listItemButton: {
         padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
         margin: theme.spacing(0.25),
         borderRadius: '50%',

       },
     },

     active: {
       color: theme.palette.primary.main,
     },
   }));

   const jobTitles = [
     'Web Developer',
     'Father',
     'Veteran',
     'Fantasy Football Champion',
     'Full-Stack Developer',
     'Cook',
     'Software Engineer',
     'Gamer',
     'Traveler',
     'Life Long Learner',
     'Investigator',
   ];

   const Sidebar = () => {
     const classes = useStyles();
     const displayedTitle = useTypingEffect(jobTitles, 150, 2000);

     return (
       <Box className={classes.sidebarContainer}>
         <Box display="flex" flexGrow={1}>{/* Add this wrapper Box */}
           {/* Nav links container */}
           <Box
             display="flex"
             flexDirection="column"
             alignItems="flex-start" // Align the items to the left side
             justifyContent="space-between" // Distribute the items evenly along the column
             pl={5}
             pr={1}
             mt={13}
             style={{ height: "100%" }} // Set the height to 100% to fill the available space
           >
             <NavLink
               to="/"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <HomeIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
             <NavLink
               to="/about"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <InfoIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
             <NavLink
               to="/projects"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <CodeIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
             <NavLink
               to="/skills"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <BuildIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
             <NavLink
               to="/experience"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <WorkIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
             <NavLink
               to="/education"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <SchoolIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
             <NavLink
               to="/contact"
               activeClassName={classes.active}
               className={classes.listItem}
             >
               <IconButton className={classes.listItemButton}>
                 <EmailIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </NavLink>
           </Box>
           {/* Avatar container */}
           <Box className={classes.avatarContainer}>
             <Avatar alt="Your Name" src="ANDY.jpeg" className={classes.avatar} />
             <Typography variant="h4" mt={2}>
               Cory Anderson
             </Typography>
             <Typography
               variant="subtitle1"
               mt={1}
               sx={{ minHeight: '1.75rem', color: 'rgb(0, 100, 0)' }}
             >
               <span className="typing-container">{displayedTitle}</span>
             </Typography>

             <Box mt={2} display="flex" flexDirection="row" gap="16px">
               <IconButton
                 href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/cory-anderson-1b1492117/"
                 target="_blank"
                 color="secondary"
               >
                 <LinkedIn />
               </IconButton>
               <IconButton
                 href="https://github.com/andydarknessb"
                 target="_blank"
                 color="secondary"
               >
                 <GitHub />
               </IconButton>
             </Box>
           </Box>
         </Box> {/* Close the wrapper Box */}
       </Box>
     );
   };

   export default Sidebar;
   ```

```
Projects.js:

import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ScrollableContent from '../ScrollableContent/ScrollableContent';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Roboto',
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Oxygen-Sans',
      'Ubuntu',
      'Cantarell',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'sans-serif',
    ].join(','),
  },
});

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textBox: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.8)',
    borderRadius: '1rem',
    padding: '1rem 0',
    zIndex: 1000,
    marginLeft: '0px',
    height: '75vh',
    marginTop: '11%',
    marginBottom: '80%',
    marginRight: '80px',
    boxShadow: '0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    border: '3px solid #333',
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease-in-out',
    '&:hover': {
      boxShadow: '0 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      transform: 'scale(1.02)',
    },
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: '#333',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  content: {
    fontSize: '1rem',
    lineHeight: 1.6,
    color: '#444',
    fontWeight: 400,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    padding: '5px',
  },
}));

function Projects() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box className={classes.textBox}>
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
          Projects:
        </Typography>
        <ScrollableContent>
          <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom className={classes.content}>
            
          </Typography>
          {/* Add CodersRank Portfolio widget */}
          <codersrank-portfolio username="andydarknessb"></codersrank-portfolio>
        </ScrollableContent>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

```
Home.js:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ScrollableContent from '../ScrollableContent/ScrollableContent';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  homeContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.8)',
    borderRadius: '1rem',
    padding: '2rem',
    zIndex: 1000,
    height: '65vh',
    marginTop: '11%',
    marginBottom: '80%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    maxWidth: '80%',
    boxShadow: '0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    border: '3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)',
    borderColor: '#4E4E4E',
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease-in-out',
    '&:hover': {
      boxShadow: '0 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      transform: 'scale(1.02)',
    },
  },
  title: {
    color: '#4E4E4E',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: '1rem',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  subTitle: {
    color: '#4E4E4E',
    marginBottom: '2rem',
    lineHeight: '1.5',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  contentWrapper: {
    overflowY: 'auto',
    maxHeight: 'calc(65vh - 3rem)',
    padding: '0 1rem',
    paddingRight: '10px', // Add desired padding value
  },
}));

const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsMounted(true);
    }, 100);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  if (!isMounted) return null;

  return (
    <Box className={classes.homeContainer}>
      <Typography variant="h2" component="h1" gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
        Welcome to My Website
      </Typography>
      <ScrollableContent>
        <Box pl={5} pr={5}> {/* Add padding to the content */}
          <Typography variant="h5" component="p" gutterBottom className={classes.subTitle}>
            How a Full Stack Developer Got Lost in a Stack of Pancakes and Still Made It To Your Screen
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </ScrollableContent>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```
//Aboutme.js
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography,} from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ScrollableContent from '../ScrollableContent/ScrollableContent';


const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Roboto',
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Oxygen-Sans',
      'Ubuntu',
      'Cantarell',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'sans-serif',
    ].join(','),
  },
});
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textBox: {
    position: 'relative', // Add relative positioning
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.8)',
    borderRadius: '1rem',
    padding: '1rem 0',
    zIndex: 1000,
    marginLeft: '0px',
    height: '75vh',
    marginTop: '11%',
    marginBottom: '80%',
    marginRight: '80px',
    boxShadow: '0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 255, opacity)',
    border: '3px solid #333',
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease-in-out',
    '&:hover': {
      boxShadow: '0 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      transform: 'scale(1.02)',
    },
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: '#333',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  content: {
    fontSize: '1rem',
    lineHeight: 1.6,
    color: '#444',
    fontWeight: 400,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    padding: '5px', // Add padding to the content

    
  },
}));


function AboutMe() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box className={classes.textBox}>
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
          About Me:
        </Typography>
        <ScrollableContent> 
        <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom className={classes.content}>
    
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom className={classes.content}>
    
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom className={classes.content}>
    
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom className={classes.content}>
    
  </Typography>
</ScrollableContent>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default AboutMe;
```

```
Contact.js:

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Box, TextField, Button, Typography, Snackbar } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  contactContainer: {
    paddingTop: '32px',
    marginTop: '64px',
  },
  contactForm: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    gap: '16px',
  },
  contactTextField: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  contactButton: {
    marginTop: '16px',
  },
}));

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

const Contact = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/send-message', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, message }),
});


      if (response.ok) {
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
        setOpen(true);
      } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to send message');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" className={classes.contactContainer}>
      <Typography variant="h4" align="center" gutterBottom>
        Contact
      </Typography>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.contactForm}>
        <TextField
          label="Name"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          className={classes.contactTextField}
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          className={classes.contactTextField}
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Message"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline
          rows={4}
          required
          className={classes.contactTextField}
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.contactButton}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
          Message sent successfully!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

```
Education.js

import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.8)',
    padding: theme.spacing(10),
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      padding: theme.spacing(5),
    },
    marginTop: '7rem',
    boxShadow: '0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    border: '3px solid #333',
    borderRadius: '1rem',
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 700,
    color: '#333',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  education: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
  },
  educationWidget: {
    '--item-bg-color': 'white',
    '--item-border-radius': '5px',
    '--item-box-shadow': '0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
    '--title-text-color': '#333',
    '--title-font-size': '1.1rem',
    '--title-font-weight': 'bold',
    '--description-text-color': '#555',
    '--description-font-size': '1rem',
    '--date-text-color': '#777',
    '--date-font-size': '0.9rem',
    '--certificate-link-text-color': '#77aaff',
    '--certificate-link-text-transform': 'none',
    '--certificate-link-hover-text-decoration': 'underline',
    '--section-title-text-color': '#777',
    '--section-title-font-size': '1.5rem',
    '--section-title-font-weight': 'bold',
    '--section-title-text-transform': 'uppercase',
  },
}));

function Education() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box className={classes.container}>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
        Education
      </Typography>
      <Box className={classes.education}>
        <codersrank-education
          username="andydarknessb"
          max-items="3"
          education="true"
          certificates="true"
          certificates-link="true"
          certificates-link-text="See certification"
          education-section-title=""
          certificates-section-title=""
          branding="false"
          className={classes.educationWidget}
        ></codersrank-education>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Education;
```

```
Experience.js:

import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ScrollableContent from '../ScrollableContent/ScrollableContent';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Roboto',
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Oxygen-Sans',
      'Ubuntu',
      'Cantarell',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'sans-serif',
    ].join(','),
  },
});

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textBox: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.8)',
    borderRadius: '1rem',
    padding: '1rem 0',
    zIndex: 1000,
    marginLeft: '0px',
    height: '75vh',
    marginTop: '11%',
    marginBottom: '80%',
    marginRight: '80px',
    boxShadow: '0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    border: '3px solid #333',
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease-in-out',
    '&:hover': {
      boxShadow: '0 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      transform: 'scale(1.02)',
    },
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: '#333',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

const Experience = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box className={classes.textBox}>
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
          Experience
        </Typography>
        <ScrollableContent>
          <codersrank-work-experience username="andydarknessb" logos></codersrank-work-experience>
        </ScrollableContent>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Experience;
```

Comment: There is too much code, it's hard to debug. You don't have to post the full code, a  minimal, reproducible example with debug details is better.